# flutter go_router unnecessary rebuild on push and go back

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

Here is example of test app: [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c80ae8e96a63857824719c3cd1fc946b)

Inside app we have 2 main routes: `ListPage` and `ListItemViewScreen`.
`ListItemViewScreen` is child route from `ListPage`.
*In this case, `ShellRoute` used only for example*

**Problem:** when we click on any item in list(row 81 - push), `ListPage` rebuild and `_loadData()` function is called. And when we go back from `ListItemViewScreen`, `ListPage` rebuild too.

How to prevent this unnecessary rebuild?

Comment: if you want to retain the page dont used goNamed but PushNamed and also it can be pop so the back tree of the current page wont rebuild again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you actually **call the function** `_loadData()` within the `build` method. This is generally a bad practice.

Instead, convert the widget into a `StatefulWidget`, set up a member that will hold the future, assign value to it in `initState`, and use this member in the `FutureBuilder` as `future` (see `_loadDataFuture`):

```
class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String type;
  const ListPage({Key? key, required this.type}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListPage> createState() => _ListPageState();
}

class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
  late final Future<int> _loadDataFuture;
  
  Future<int> _loadData() {
    print("Emulate load data from DB: ${widget.type}");
    return Future.value(1);
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadDataFuture = _loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _loadDataFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) => ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              context.push("/list/${widget.type}/view/$index");
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Text("item_$index"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It is possible that at some point you do want to re-execute the future after it is completed. In the case, remove the `final` from the declaration of `_loadDataFutre`, and if you'd like to trigger a reload, use:

```
setState(() {
  _loadDataFuture = _loadData();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just curious, why after return(go back), widget rebuild. How I understand, ListPage in pages stack, and when we return, it already have state and everything what it need.

Comment: You can't really know and control how often widgets are rebuilt by Flutter engine. Every time the engine thinks it is necessary, it will call `build`.

Comment: For example if you have a widget which calls `MediaQuery.of(context)` will be rebuilt a dozen times whenever the soft keypad is opening with an animation.

Comment: So you need to avoid every call in a `build` method that does not need to run every time. In some cases `build` method can be called many times within a second!

Comment: In real app, I use for this future function from provider. Is this method is normal?
```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _loadDBFuture = context.read<DocumentsProvider>().loadDB(widget.status);
    });
  }
```

Comment: or maybe there is best approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252273/discussion-between-smie-and-peter-koltai).